# Running pydoop tasks in Python programm

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop

There are many examples in [PyDoop documentation](http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/tutorial/pydoop_script.html#examples) showing, how to run PyDoop script from shell, but I need to run  pydoop task within function in my python system.

Here is example of function:

```
def mrb2(inp, out):
        class CountMapper(api.Mapper):
            def map(self, context):
                context.emit(context.value.split()[0], 1)

        class CheckReducer(api.Reducer):
            def reduce(self, context):
                context.emit(context.key, sum(context.values))

        pipes.run_task(api.Factory(CountMapper, CheckReducer), istream=inp, ostream=out)
```

The `inp` and `out` is opened plain text files:

```
with open('input.txt') as inp, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
     ...
```

But when I try to run I get an error:

```
pipes.run_task(api.Factory(CountMapper, CheckReducer), istream=inp, ostream=out)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. modules `api`, `pipes` imported from `pydoop.mapreduce`.